# python - Convert float into integer in a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, floating-point, integer

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
'T': [11.0,22.0,11.23,20.03],
'v2': [11.0,13.0,55.1,33.0],
'v3' : [112.1,2.0,2.1,366.0],
'v4': [np.nan, "blue", 1.0, 2.0]
 })

       T    v2     v3    v4
0  11.00  11.0  112.1   NaN
1  22.00  13.0    2.0  blue
2  11.23  55.1    2.1   1.0
3  20.03  33.0  366.0   2.0
```

and I must have:

```
    T       v2     v3    v4
0  11     11.0  112.1   NaN
1  22     13.0    2.0  blue
2  11.23  55.1    2.1   1.0
3  20.03  33.0  366.0   2.0
```

So I have to transform float to integer only on 'T.'

Comment: can you add more content to the question.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible, but a bit hack, because is necessary converting to `object`:

```
df3['T'] = np.array([int(x) if int(x) == x else x for x in df3['T']], dtype=object)
print (df3)
       T    v2     v3    v4
0     11  11.0  112.1   NaN
1     22  13.0    2.0  blue
2  11.23  55.1    2.1     1
3  20.03  33.0  366.0     2

print (df3['T'].tolist())
[11, 22, 11.23, 20.03]
```

If possible missing values:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
'T': [11.0,22.0,11.23,np.nan],
'v2': [11.0,13.0,55.1,33.0],
'v3' : [112.1,2.0,2.1,366.0],
'v4': [np.nan, "blue", 1.0, 2.0]
 })


df3['T'] = np.array([int(x) if x % 1 == 0 else x for x in df3['T']], dtype=object)
print (df3)
       T    v2     v3    v4
0     11  11.0  112.1   NaN
1     22  13.0    2.0  blue
2  11.23  55.1    2.1     1
3    NaN  33.0  366.0     2

print (df3['T'].tolist())
[11, 22, 11.23, nan]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the same idea of @jezrael but with [is_integer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'T': [11.0, 22.0, 11.23, 20.03],
    'v2': [11.0, 13.0, 55.1, 33.0],
    'v3': [112.1, 2.0, 2.1, 366.0],
    'v4': [np.nan, "blue", 1.0, 2.0]
})

df3['T'] = np.array([int(x) if float(x).is_integer() else x for x in df3['T']], dtype=object)

print(df3)
```

**Output**

```
T    v2     v3    v4
0     11  11.0  112.1   NaN
1     22  13.0    2.0  blue
2  11.23  55.1    2.1     1
3  20.03  33.0  366.0     2
```

Or using [numpy.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [numpy.fmod](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fmod.html#numpy.fmod):

```
mask = np.fmod(df3['T'].values, 1) == 0
df3['T'] = np.where(mask, df3['T'].values.astype(np.int), df3['T']).astype(dtype=object)
print(df3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or why not:

```
df3=df3.apply(lambda x: int(x) if int(x)==x and x==x and isinstance(x,float) else x)
```

And now:

```
print(df3)
```

Is gonna be expected output:

```
    T       v2     v3    v4
0  11     11.0  112.1   NaN
1  22     13.0    2.0  blue
2  11.23  55.1    2.1   1.0
3  20.03  33.0  366.0   2.0
```